# Find table row by a given cell value and delete that row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 3 columns-

```
<table id="my_list">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>column 1</th>
        <th>column 2</th>
        <th>column 3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>value 1</td>
        <td>value 2</td>
        <td>value 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm writing a function that searches the table for a `given_value` and deletes the row that contains it-

```
function delete_row (given_value) {
    var table_row = $("td").filter(function() {
        return $('#my_list').text() == given_value;
    }).closest("tr");

    // Removing the row from `my_list` table
    table_row.remove();

}
```

But this is not deleting the row.

Also, I only want to search the text values in `column 2`, so if there's a faster way to search the table, that would be great to know too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, but you can loop over the `td` elements and check their text and if you get a match, delete the `tr` element.

Edit: If you wanted to specify an id, you could add that to the function like such. Then just give the function the id name and what value to look for.

```js
function delete_row(id, given_value) {
  var td = $("#" + id + " td");
  $.each(td, function(i) {
    if ($(td[i]).text() === given_value) {
      $(td[i]).parent().remove();
    } 
  });
}

delete_row('my_list', 'value 1');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my_list">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>column 1</th>
    <th>column 2</th>
    <th>column 3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>value 1</td>
    <td>value 2</td>
    <td>value 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the input! Although I was wondering how does the code know which table to search for the data, since you're not giving the table ID

Comment: @kev You could add an extra param there and specify which id you wanted to target: https://jsfiddle.net/90szbhtq/

Comment: and how would the code change? Also, right now I'm not specifying any ID, but it just assumes the table I want to search (probably because that's the only table on my page ?)

Comment: Did you see the fiddle? Hold on I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The filter function actually passes a couple things as arguments, including the current element. To check the text of that element, rather than the text of `"#my_list"`, use `$(el).text()`.

After that, 'trim' the value of the text, to remove the whitespace before and after the text. Otherwise its comparing `' value 2 '` with `'value 2'`, and it will not produce a match.

As a side note, the standard within JavaScript is to use camelCase instead of snake_case.

```
function deleteRow(givenValue) {
  var tableRow = $("td")
    .filter(function(index, el) {
      return (
        $(el) // <-- the <td> element
          .text()
          .trim() === givenValue
      );
    })
    .closest("tr");
  // Removing the row from `my_list` table
  tableRow.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure given_value matches the html text? There's spaces before and after text which may be your problem. Also, make sure table_row is not empty after the filter function.

```
function delete_row(given_value) {
    var table_row = $("td").filter(function () {
        return $('#my_list').text() == given_value;
    });

    if (table_row.length > 0) {
        // Removing the row from `my_list` table
        table_row.closest("tr").remove();
    } else {
        console.log('nothing matching given_value!')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this simple code:**

```
function RemoveFromTable(tblID, VALUE){
     $("#"+tblID).find("td:contains('"+VALUE+"')").closest('tr').remove();
}
```

**Call the function as follows:**

```
RemoveFromTable('table ID','value')
```

Comment: Hi Dilip.  I removed your "Thanks" line because it's generally preferred not to include it in posts, see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950) for why.

Answer (score -1):

You need to match `<td>` instead of the entire table. Then trim the value to remove any leading/trailing white spaces. Then use the index parameter from the filter function to get the `nth <td>` element (using `eq`) and check its value for the desired value, and then remove it.

```
function delete_row (given_value) {
    var table_row = $("td").filter(function(idx) {
        return $("td").eq(idx).text().trim() == given_value;
    });

    // Removing the row from `my_list` table
    table_row.remove();

}
```

I would also suggest to set the value to be an empty string so as to not disrupt the structure of the table.

Comment: Solution is removing cell(s) not row(s). Also doing a lot of extra work to look for the `<td>` by index when it's already available as `this` in callback